# Multiple independent variable cases in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a random roller where 5 variables need to be rolled for a set and then a string printed depending on each variable, but with the exact same conditions but are all independent of each other. The output would then print a list of those strings.

Instead of writing:

```
n1 = rand(a..f)+a
n2 = rand(a..f)+a
...
n5 = rand(a..f)+a

case n1
when a..c
  puts x
when d..f
  puts y
else
  puts z
end

case n2
when a..c
  puts x
when d..f
  puts y
else
  puts z
end

...

case n5
when a..c
  puts x
when d..f
  puts y
else
  puts z
end
```

Is there a way to write the case as multiple independent variables in an array or something similar so I'd only need to write the conditions once? There could be up to 4 of these sets if the user is unlucky enough to roll that many, and I don't want to have to write the same conditions up to 20 times, as in my particular situation, there are actually 29 conditions for each case.

Comment: write a method for the case and then pass the variables to the method one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to encapsulate the logic you have in a method that you can apply multiple times. You have a simplified example, but I'll provide a slightly more robust example here to get you on the right path of thinking:

```
class RollValue
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def message
    case @value
    when a..c
      puts 'x'
    when d..f
      puts 'y'
    else
      puts 'z'
    end
  end
end

RollValue.new('b').message #=> 'x'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I've applied it to and tested different sets and it does exactly what I want. Thank you very much!